# Save .Find() function results to array Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'd like to save all found numbers of rows containing the string into the array. I've written a function which works properly but I can't save its results into array. I might do it saving not as .Row values but .Address as strings however it's not my goal. I tried change array type from integer to long, but that does not work. Have u any idea what i should to do? What is the type of value .Row? By manual .Find() function return Range type, but I'm not sure that .Row value is also Range. If it is how to use this knowledge to solve the problem?
My code:

```
Function findTesterRows(przypisFileName As String, testerName As String, tableSize As Integer) As Integer()
Dim tableRange As String
    tableRange = "A2:L" & tableSize
Dim myArray() As Integer
Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

With Workbooks(przypisFileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(tableRange)
    Set foundRow = .Find(What:=testerName, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not foundRow Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = foundRow.Address
        Do
            i = i + 1
            Set foundRow = .FindNext(foundRow)
        Loop While Not foundRow Is Nothing And foundRow.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

ReDim myArray(0, i)
i = 0

 With Workbooks(przypisFileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(tableRange)
    Set foundRow = .Find(What:=testerName, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not foundRow Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = foundRow.Address
        Do
            MsgBox foundRow.Row
            myArray(i) = foundRow.Row '!!HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!
            i = i + 1
            Set foundRow = .FindNext(foundRow)
        Loop While Not foundRow Is Nothing And foundRow.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

findTesterRows = myArray

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out how you redimensioned the array to `ReDim myArray(0,i)`.  Then look at how you're calling it later, `myArray(i) = foundRow.Row`.

The second index is missing.  Try doing `myArray(0,i) = foundRow.Row`.

Then, to return all the foundrows, you can do something like

```
for i = lbound(myArray) to ubound(myArray)
 debug.print "Rows are: " & myArray(0,i)
next i
```

Comment: I can't belive it. I instead type ReDim myArray(0 To i), I typed ReDim myArray(0, i). Its working now, thanks for help, and sorry for stupid question.

Comment: @mathsicist - haha, it happens to the best of us.  I have since invested in a [rubber ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/rubber_duck_debugging) who helps out in times like that. :P  (Mind marking as answer if it worked?)